# Nested/Multiple IF functions in excel, how can I?

Tags: excel, if-statement, nested

I am trying to implement an excel spreadsheet to keep track of my working hours.

I am entitled to unpaid breaks at my work, however these vary depending on the length of shift as follows.

0 - 3.75 hours = 0 min break

4 - 5.75 hours = 15 min break

6 - 7.75 hours = 30 min break

8 - 8.75 hours = 45 min break

9 - 11.75 hours = 90 min break

I would like to calculate my working hours minus breaks in excel.

I think I need to use if statement similar to the following (taking E2 as my hours):

```
=if(E2<=3.75, E2, if(4<=E2<=5.75, E2-30, if(6<=E2...etc...
```

But it never seems to work, can someone help me get this working???

Thanks.

Comment: What break are you entitled to for, say, 8.8 hours?

Comment: We tend to be given shifts to the hour, half past or quarter to, so .5 or .75. Would never get given an 8.8 hour shift

Comment: Which version of Excel are you using?

Comment: I just downloaded the most recent version from the Office website, I am aware of IFS statements but my Excel doesn't recognise when I put =ifs into the cell, frustrating!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this:

```
=IF(E2<=3.75,0,IF(AND(E2>=4,E2<=5.75),15,IF(AND(E2>=6,E2<=7.75),30,IF(AND(E2>=8,E2<=8.75),45,IF(AND(E2>=9,E2<=11.75),90,"")))))
```

<s>***EDIT : 1***</s>

```
=IF(E2<=3.75,E2,IF(AND(E2>=4,E2<=5.75),(E2*1440-15)/1440,IF(AND(E2>=6,E2<=7.75),(E2*1440-30)/1440,IF(AND(E2>=8,E2<=8.75),(E2*1440-45)/1440,IF(AND(E2>=9,E2<=11.75),(E2*1440-90)/1440,"")))))
```

***EDIT : 2***

```
=IF(E2<=3.75,E2,IF(AND(E2>=4,E2<=5.75),E2-0.25,IF(AND(E2>=6,E2<=7.75),E2-0.5,IF(AND(E2>=8,E2<=8.75),E2-0.75,IF(AND(E2>=9,E2<=11.75),E2-1.5,"")))))
```

See image for reference.

[image]

Comment: This does work, however it's giving me results like 15, 30, which would be my break itself. I'd like this to minus my breaks from a shift. For example, if my shift was 4, this cell would output 3.75.

Comment: @SamKennethGordon - If your shift timing is 4 hours what output do you expect?

Comment: Ideally I would like a 4 hour shift to output 3.75 because I have a 15minute break.

Comment: Thank You, I appreaciate it hugely!